# Why is my function partially doing what it’s supposed to do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I’m trying to write a Python 3 function for a challenge that takes in a string, removes the vowels and returns it without the vowels. I wrote the below code but it seems to only take out the vowels partially while leaving some untouched.

```
def remove_vowels(string):
    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
    newstring = ""

    for letter in string:
        if letter in vowels:
            newstring = string.replace(letter,””)
        else:
             pass

    return newstring
```

Comment: Can you share the output too

Comment: This check is quite pointless `if letter in vowels:`

Comment: Does your string have mixed casing?

Comment: I have fixed the indentation of your code posting. Next time, please make sure to select the entire block of code before pressing the `{}` button.

Comment: Think carefully about your logic. What do you expect to happen to `newstring` when `newstring = string.replace(letter,””)` happens the first time? Okay, what about the second time? Hint: what is the thing you are calling `.replace` on the second time? Did it change since the first time?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski How is it pointless? It's an O(1) time check to avoid an O(n) time `replace`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your original python code with the following input

```
print(remove_vowels("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"))
```

returns "The quick brwn fx jumps ver the lazy dg"

The reason this only removes the "o" vowel is because your iterating through each vowel and updating your new string to the passed string minus the current vowel your on. So for example the first time through your for loop your "newstring" variable will be:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lzy dog
```

Then the next iteration your "newstring" variable will be set to

```
Th quick brown fox jumps ovr th lazy dog
```

And so on and so on. The reason my example only removes the o's is because there is no U to replace so the string replace method is never called leaving the "newstring" variables without o's.

To fix this you would just remove newstring completely and update the original string as this is it's own variable and this would technically work as is.

Although this can be compressed and refactored for better performance quite easily as you don't actually need to iterate through your string at all (nor do you need any type of new string as the passed string is it's own variable you are able to update) as pythons "String.replace" will replace ALL occurrences of the supplied substring and return the resulting string (if you don't supply a max amount of occurrences).

The following code below works

```
def remove_vowels(string):
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    for vowel in vowels: string = string.replace(vowel,'')
    return string

print(remove_vowels("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"))
```

and returns "Th qck brwn fx jmps vr th lzy dg"

Comment: In the result for the first example only the o's are removed because o is the last vowel in the original string (not because there is no u to replace).

Answer (score 6):

That's because you're setting `newstring` to a different string output on every iteration of the loop `newstring = string.replace("")`

You need to set `newstring` to the replaced string, and then run the next iteration of replace on `newstring`. Like this:

```
def remove_vowels(string):
    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
    newstring = string

    for letter in newstring:
        if letter in vowels:
            newstring = newstring.replace(letter , "")

    return newstring

string = "stack overflow"
print("Original string = ", string)
print("String with vowels removed = ", remove_vowels(string))
```

Output:

```
Original string = stack overflow
String with vowels removed = stck vrflw
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative, short solution with a [list comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/):

```py
def remove_vowels(string):
    not_vowels = [letter for letter in string if letter not in 'aeiou']
    return ''.join(not_vowels)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the following modifications to your code and it should work like a charm :)

```
def remove_vowels(string):
vowels = 'aeiou'

for letter in string:
    if letter in vowels:
        string = string.replace(letter," ")
    else:
         pass

return string
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing a character in original string each time, but the original string never changes with current logic (except in the last loop).

try this inside IF condition
`newstring = newstring.replace(letter,"")`

(also initialize newstring = string before for loop)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several defects:

- You are updating `new_string` with `string`, which does not change, and that results in only the last vowel in the list is deleted.
- You do not need `else: pass`, it's ok with only the if clause. The `else: pass` is redundant.
- You are cycling through the letters in `string`, which is not the fastest way to do things, also, it will create all kinds of weird errors if your code is changing `string`. You can knock out`for i in new_string:if i in vowels` with `for i in vowels`
- The `vowels` does not have to be a list if you are only iterating over it.Try a `tuple` or a `str` for better efficiency.

The overall fix:

```py
def remove_vowels(string):
    vowels = ('a','e','i','o','u')
    newstring = string
    for letter in vowels:
        newstring = newstring.replace(letter,””)
    return newstring
```

or:

```
def remove_vowels(string):
    vowels = ('a','e','i','o','u')
    for letter in vowels:
        string = string.replace(letter,””)
    return string
```